# In JetBrains plugin development, how to execute command in the terminal from plugin action with Gateway

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, jetbrains-gateway

I am new to plugin development for JetBrains and would like to know how I can execute a command in the terminal with JetBrains Gateway.

I've tried like this:

```java
var shellTerminalWidget = TerminalView.getInstance(project).createLocalShellWidget(currentWorkspacePath, "NewTab");
shellTerminalWidget.executeCommand(command);
```

It works well when I test locally. However, when I use JetBrains Gateway and install this plugin on the host, it doesn't work any longer, and I can't find any exceptions in the log.

Is there any difference when using Gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now such code creates an invisible terminal which should be shared explicitly:

```
BackendTerminalManager.getInstance(project).shareTerminal(...)
```

But we are going to fix in and automatically share all created local terminals in remoteDev, feel free to trach this issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-6928

Comment: Thank you very much, but I can't find the class BackendTerminalManger. How could I install the related dependencies, and how could I get some related documents. Thanks

Comment: I added the dependency and tried but this message was shown: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jetbrains/rdserver/terminal/BackendTerminalManager`. And my GoLand version is 2022.2.

Comment: Yes, you have to reference backend terminal plugin in your plugin in that case